# How to import a class from another module in Android Studio 2.0 beta 5?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to import a class from another module which is a library(A). There is another module which is android app(B). So I am trying to import A into B

**settings.gradle** :

```
include ':A', ':B'
```

**B build.gradle**   :

```
  dependencies {
    compile project(':A')   
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

}
```

When I try to do a gradle sync, it gave me the following error:

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core'. Resolved
>   versions for app (1.1) and test app (1.3) differ. See
>   http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
>
> Error:Conflict with dependency 'junit:junit'. Resolved versions for
>   app (4.8.2) and test app (4.12) differ. See
>   http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

If I remove the line:

```
    compile project(':A')
```

the gradle syncs without any error, but I cannot import the A into B.

Can someone suggest me why it is causing the error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that the following dependencies are already added in the module A gradle file, so that I dont need to add them again in my B gradle file.

I need to remove

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

and then gradle sync went without any error.

Now I am able to import the module A into B.

Comment: THANKS MAN, THIS TOTALLY HELPED ME YOU ARE AWESOME!

Comment: Wow that was a life saver